# Google Sheets: When selecting cell in separate sheets, the quick reference tip blocks my selection

Tags: google-sheets

When writing a formula that references cells in multiple sheets, when I am on a sheet other than the one where the formula is located, it provides me with a 'Tip' showing what the formula currently looks like. This 'Tip' is constantly blocking where I actually need to click to assign the cell. How do I move it or make it go away?

[image: Image showing the Tip box I would like to remove]

Answer (score 1):

you can click in any cell and then navigate to your destination with arrow keys. if your destination is range instead of single cell you press down shift key and again play with arrow keys